# Python関連パッケージのアンインストールについて

Tags: python3, linux, apt

## やりたいこと

以下のコマンドでインストールしたpython3.8やpipのパッケージのアンインストールを行いたいです。

```
sudo apt install python3.8
python3.8 -m pip install pip
```

## 行ったこと

アンインストールコマンドでpython3.8を削除しました。

```
sudo apt remove python3.8
sudo apt autoremove
```

## 状況

python3.8自体はアンインストールされました。
しかし、いくつか残骸と思われる以下のようなディレクトリが残っています。
これらのディレクトリは削除しても問題は無いのでしょうか？

```
./home/{USER}/.local/lib/python3.8
./etc/python3.8
./usr/lib/python3.8
./usr/local/lib/python3.8
./snap/core18/1279/usr/lib/python3.8
```

Comment: Ubuntu の場合、`/etc/python3.8` については `libpython3.8-minimal` パッケージに附属していますので `sudo apt purge libpython3.8-minimal` を実行すると削除されます。

Comment: `/usr/lib/python3.8` は `dpkg --search /usr/lib/python3.8` を実行すると分かるかと思いますが、`python3-distutils` などの meta package に附属している事になっています。また、`apt show python3-distutils | grep -i provides:` を実行すると `python3.8-distutils` が表示されるかと思います。これは virtual package であるため apt/dpkg コマンドでは削除することができませんので、手動で削除する方が楽でしょう。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt remove` コマンドはデフォルトでは設定ファイルを削除しません。パッケージに関連する設定ファイルも含めて削除するには
代わりに `purge` コマンドを指定してください。

```
$ sudo apt purge PACKAGE
```